# how do i make make height and wisdth full screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I dont know why but my website's css work good only if the screen is on f11 mode. also my background img cut from buttom. help pls.

```
body {
    background-image: url("bg/logo.jpg");
     margin: 0;
     cursor: url("icon/owcursor.png"), auto;
overflow: hidden; 
}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnDv8.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoaLb.jpg]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.
Width: 100%;
Height: 100%;

Comment: hi. no. some why the css work like the page isnoy 1920x1080 and if i write Width: 1920px; Height: 1080px; its make scroller and idont wanjt scroller

Comment: Like others have said, you need to provide more details.

Comment: the google count the toolbar  and this stuff also from the website

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information, you can use:

height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;